# Identify movie with shrunken man fighting a wasp

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have very vague memories of this movie – I saw bits of it when I was a kid. I watched it in the 90s, and it felt like a 90s movie. It was in color, and in English. Most likely American, but I am not sure. It felt like a drama with some dark-ish comedy.

The first thing I remember is a father and son in a horse-drawn carriage. The father is telling the son that the place he's taking him will be good for him. It was dark, I think.

Next thing I remember is the son on a table, shrunk to the size of a salt shaker. He is attacked by a wasp, and defends himself with a needle, eventually killing the wasp.

Finally, the son is in a hallway that's his size. He comes to a door that's answered by a woman. He asks to come in, but she requires a gift. He offers the stinger of the wasp he killed.

That's all I remember. I've always been bugged by the fact I can't find any mention of a movie that seems to match this plot. Any help is appreciated.  The son seemed to be in his early- to mid-twenties.

Comment: Shrunken man fights a wasp you say? https://youtu.be/pWdKf3MneyI

Comment: @cde lol, not quite

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gulliver's Travels (1996)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115195/), perhaps?

It wasn't a "son" but Gulliver fighting wasps (during his time in a Land of Giants), he did took wasp stinger and later on gave it as a gift to a woman behind the door to source of immortality.

Comment: YAY! This is exactly right.